convert pwm pin to on off relay
I have an ortur laser controller which drives the fiber laser.
As i can see thre is red black and on pwm cable.

I want to replace the whole laser circuit in picture with just a relay.
And i want controller to drive relay.
if pwm over 20% relay is on if <20% relay is off
can someone provide a simple circuit ??

How does the relay and laser coincide? Please draw a schematic.
